# Failing to import posts from XML in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, import

I am trying to import my posts and comments from another wordpress site but it's failing every time. After I'm selecting the users, it's just showing a blank page. The XML file it's 49MB which I think it's not a problem since Wordpress it's accepting files up to 64MB.

Comment: Can you let us know what you mean by it is failing?  Is it timing out?

Comment: No it's not timing out, it's uploading, i'm selecting the users from which to post and when i click import, it returns a blank page.

Comment: if the XML method is not working I would recommend doing it the manual way through SQL.  Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress